# Notepad/text-editor encrypt on Android, decrypt on linux -- and vice-versa

Tags: linux, encryption, notes, text-editor

I'm looking for an encrypted notepad or text editor for Android which encrypts files in a way that allows them to be decrypted under Linux.
I also want this to work in the opposite direction: encrypting a file under Linux and having it be decryptable under the same encrypted notepad or text editor under Android.

It's important to me that the encryption and decryption under Android get done with one, single step. I don't want to perform a manual pre-encryption or pre-decryption step under Android. I want to simply open the file via some sort of encryption-enabled app under Android, edit its contents using that same app, and then save it encrypted using that same app ... so that the file is also decryptable and re-encryptable under Linux.

I don't care if multiple steps are needed under Linux, because I can encapsulate those steps within a script on that operating system. Furthermore, I want the encryption/decryption under Linux to be performed using command-line tools, not via some sort of GUI-based application, because I plan to implement this Linux-based encryption and decryption within emacs. Therefore, I'm looking for the Android encryption to be done via some sort of standard encryption algorithms.

To be clear, I expect to have to use the same encryption/decryption password for these files both under Android and Linux.

I know how to transfer files between Android and Linux, and I'm not looking for help with that. This question simply has to do with the encryption/decryption.

Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: So actually you are searching for an encrypted text editor Android app, right? Please note that questions about app recommendations are considered off-topic.

Comment: Oh, OK. I'm Sorry

Comment: You can use shell scripts on Android too to avoid the hassle of multiple steps, like you can do on Linux. But that's not necessary. Give `encfs` a try. Luckily MiXplorer has both features built-in; `encfs` encryption and a simple text editor. But you have to encrypt/decrypt the directory containing your file(s). It's easily decryptable in a single step on Linux too.